# Second monitor blurry -- fractional scaling? Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, multiple-monitors, display, display-resolution

I've seen this question asked in other places, but I couldn't find a definitive, system-wide answer. So, I have a second monitor, a 4K Gigabyte M28U that I'm running at 120 Hz with fractional scaling set to 175%. On Ubuntu 22.04, the text in many non-GNOME apps comes across as blurry, while default Gnome apps have nice, crisp text. Take for instance a comparison between a code snippet in my terminal vs. on Google Chrome in Stack Exchange:[image: Side by side comparison of GNOME terminal and code snippet in Stack Exchange on Chrome]

Or a comparison of a PDF in Document Viewer vs. PDF viewer in VS Code:
[image: Side by side comparison of text in a PDF viewed in Document Viewer vs. in VS Code's PDF viewer]

I assume this has something to do with fractional scaling. I also assume that images/video viewed on my 4K monitor are also getting blurred, but are just hard to see as the image is more complex than simple text.

Is there anything at all to be done about this? It's really frustrating splurging on a high-res monitor only for all the non-GNOME apps to be blurry.

Thank you!